# Moment.js showing invalid date in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have a date coming in UTC format from the server, I am trying to convert it to user's local timezone and then format the date as per my need. In chrome browser its working fine but in Mozilla browser its keeps showing the invalid date. Below is my code for converting dates to local.

```
 getUtcTimeAsPerUser(date: any) {
   moment
      .utc(date)
      .local()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");}
```

I used so many different approaches but haven't got any success. I tried below code as per some suggestions in a stack but it's not working in Mozilla.

```
const local = moment.utc(date).local();
const momentFormat = moment(local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Please help me or suggest any other approach to convert date into user's local timezone. Thank you.

Comment: in what format can `date` parameter in the function be expected? can you give an example

Comment: @VandanaChandola from server, the date is coming like this "02-27-2020 13:15:25"

Comment: Hmm, looks like your input is in the format `MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss` and not `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. Change that and I believe it should work. Like this: `let newDate: string  = moment.utc(date, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss").local().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome supports more date formats than Firefox. In Firefox you should use RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formats for dates -- e.g. `2011-12-01T01:23:45+06:00` is in ISO 8601.

Also, you can just specify the input format when creating the MomentJS object:

```
const local = moment.utc(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss').local();
const momentFormat = moment(local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: currently the format coming from server is like this "02-27-2020 13:15:25" , if I covert this date to ISO format first and then do operation , then it will work right?

Comment: see my update, you can specify a format when creating the momentjs object.